Not able to add noise in the white area of the rendered image
I tried to add some noise to my image during compositing after rendering.
Here are the node configurations I used:

The Film Grain node group is defined in this blend file and described in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQHmYJh-uvQ.
This setup works perfectly in dark areas, but it doesn't work in white areas. As you can see from the image below, the white part contains no noise.

Why does the white area contain no noise? How can I add noise to the white areas too?
Any help would be appreciated!

What happens when you switch it to a different blend mode like multiply or overlay?
